# How to know particular column has foreign key violation when insert a statement from c# windows application?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know how to identify a particular exception from C# code by using `SqlException` class.

By using `SqlException` I found exception number in my catch block and I compared with the particular error number and i wrote my own user friendly message to the user.

But when the foreign key violation occurred, I just compare 547 error number and I wrote foreign key violation. I thought this is not enough to display a message to user. Instead of this I want to show a foreign key column also to the user. How to get this column?

Thanks

Comment: It is not available in exception? you can extract that column name from SQLException and use it in your Custom message

Comment: one more thing is 547 is not just Foreign key violation but constraint violation

Comment: You should be able to extract the name of the constraint that is violated and then look up the type and definition of the constraint and determine what tables and columns it involves. Most likely `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` has this info. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/17/sql-server-two-methods-to-retrieve-list-of-primary-keys-and-foreign-keys-of-database/

Comment: Looks like you'll need to manually extract it from the exception string.

Comment: @ManojNaik. Yes, but how can i extract from that exception string? Suppose i have a 3 foreign key columns in my table then how to identify exception is raised by this column?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can parse error message like this

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{  
    switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
    {
        case 547: // Foreign Key violation
            string s = ex.Message;
            s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("column "));
            string[] array = s.Split('.');
            s = array[0].Substring(array[0].IndexOf('\''));               
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this tells me the column in the target table, not the source table. I wonder if it would still work if SQL Server were installed with a locale other than English.